# How do I enable access to Application variables inside a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I know I can allow the web service access to Session variables by adding (EnableSession=true). Is there a way to allow it access to global Application variables?

I have several resource intensive variables that are loaded in the Global.asax and I need access to there in the webservice.

Comment: Never mind. For some reason I thought that the application was not available from within a web service by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store them in static properties which will be accessible from your web methods. Make sure to synchronize the access to such shared resources though. As an alternative you could use the global Application object to store values that should be shared among all requests.